# How do I calculate the effective HP of a unit given two multiplicative percent reductions?

Tags: calculus

A unit has 100 health, 50% armor, 50% damage mitigation when attacked, the mitigation applies after the armor reduction such that it takes 400 damage to kill the unit in one hit. I call this effective HP.

How do I figure this 'damage to kill in one hit' number out through a formula for any given armor percent and damage mitigation percent?

Simplest example:

```
HP = 100
Armor = 0%
Mitigation = 0%
Effective HP = 100
```

```
Example 2:
HP = 100
Armor = 50%
Mitigation = 0%
Effective HP = 200
```

```
Example 3:
HP = 100
Armor = 50%
Mitigation = 50%
Effective HP = 400
```

Edit:

`HP / (percent_1_decimal * percent_2_decimal)`

`Example 3 almost-solution: 100 / (0.5 * 0.5)`

Almost works, except if one of the percent_decimals is 0, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples 2 and 3 are inconsistent in applying the armor and mitigation.  I would think when armor or mitigation is $50\%$ it would multiply the damage by $(1-50\%)$ or divide the damage by $2$.  That would correspond to example $3$ where the damage is divided by $2$ twice, so divided by $4$.  In example $2$ it would give Effective HP=$200$ instead of $150$.  Of course, the software you are using may not be consistent.

Comment: Yes sorry I messed up example 2's effective HP

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out finally, the formula is
`Damage = HP / ((1 - Armor_Percent_Decimal_Form) * (1 - Mitigation_Percent_Decimal_Form))`

@Ross Millikan was right that my example 2 was wrong/inconsistent, my bad
it should have been `effective HP = 200`

So for example 3

```
100 / ((1 - 0.5) * (1 - 0.5)) = 400
```

Example 1

```
100 / ((1 - 0.0) * (1 - 0.0)) = 100
```

Example 2

```
100 / ((1 - 0.5) * (1 - 0.0)) = 200
```

This formula doesn't work (divide 0 error) when I use 100% for one of the percentages, because the effective HP then would be infinite, but that's good enough for me

Answer (score 0):

I have the following guess, based on the mechanic I would expect from a game: armor doesn't reduce a percentage of the damage, it increase your HP by a percentage. So we have $EHP\cdot (1-M) = HP\cdot(1+A)$, so $$EHP = \frac{HP \cdot (1+A)}{1-M}$$

That's what seems logic to me (but then your example 3 doesn't fit)